# Word 2013 freezes on saving

Tags: windows-8, freeze, microsoft-word-2013

Word 2013 freezes when I try to save a file.

I am installing all of the updates from Windows update and running office install again and selecting "repair it", but I still have problems when I want to save a file, it freezes and no solution works except to close or end task.

When it freezes, the opened file is deleted and no longer exists, instead in its directory are temp files like `~WRD0002.tmp`. I rename the temp files to `myfile.docx` and when open it, see the last auto save of file.

My operating system is Windows 8.1. What is the solution of this big problem?

Comment: How long does it freeze?  Have you signed into your Microsoft Account?  Are you saving these files locally?

Comment: @Ramhound: no, i don't log in to ?Microsoft Account, files saved locally. it's freezed forever!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by changing which drive I was saving my word files to. I had been trying to save to the drive where I have Windows installed, but moving to another drive solved the problem.

Comment: @Twisty: He *is* the author and just solved his own problem with a workaround.

Comment: Oops, missed that in the review queue. @AliSh, you should mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Twisty : I will accept it, but i must wait for 48 hours:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
"You can also accept your own answer, but you must wait 48 hours to do so. After all, someone else may come along with an even better solution to your problem!"